# Get Pseudorandom number generator Seed Value From List

Tags: python, random

Let's say I want to generate a random integer list, so I use this program, and set my seed to 10:

```
import random
random.seed(10)
randomlist = random.sample(range(0, 5), 5)
print(randomlist)
```

The output will be always [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
because I set my seed to 10. That's why I get the same result over and over.

But my question is: it possible to get the seed number from an unknown random value?

For instance, I have a random list:

```
mylist = [3, 2, 0, 1, 2] # 5 item with range of 0 to 5
```

I wrote this random list my own, (I didn't use any kind of program), but I can generate the same random list with the `random` module and the help of loop - just pass the loop iteration in `random.seed()` function on my previous program.

But I want to get the seed value from the "mylist" variable without a loop, like so:

```
def GetSeed(mylist,start_range,stop_range):
    return "And The Program returned the seed number"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Python uses the Mersenne Twister: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/is-it-possible-to-find-a-mersenne-twister-seed-given-only-the-first-output

Comment: What's the meaning of `start_range` and `stop_range`?

Comment: check below answer

Answer (score 1):

Albeit it not being the best solution, you could always try brute-forcing it. That is, follow the same algorithm you followed to create the list for every number, starting at 0, until you get a result.
The `GetSeed` function would look something like this:

```
def GetSeed(mylist, start_range, stop_range):
    listlen = len(mylist)
    i = 0
    randomlist = []

    while randomlist != mylist:
        random.seed(i)
        randomlist = random.sample(range(start_range, stop_range), listlen)

        i += 1
        
    return i - 1
```

This algorithm will sometimes yield a different result than the seed used, especially for lists with smaller sample ranges. This is because some seeds will give you the same list as other seeds. Therefore, instead of getting the actual seed used, you'll only be able to get the minimum seed that gives the list. For example, running `GetSeed([4, 0, 1, 2, 3], 0, 5)` will return 6 instead of 10. This is because, were you to give the seed 6 in the initial example, you'd get the same result as you did with the seed 10. I assume, however, that any approach to the problem would have this drawback.

Generally, the smaller your sample range, the higher the chances this might occur. This is true, because when you limit your range, it's more likely that two seeds that produced different numbers ended up giving you the same number in your list.

Comment: if the function return more than 1 seed value thats also okay. those seed always return the expected List... But thats not a Solution because as i mention in my post that loop is not acceptable because if i expend my random.sample(range(a, b), c) then its take more time and more compute power to find the seed, thats why i ask for a algorithm that return the seed value without any loop

Comment: I didn't notice you wanted a solution without a loop; but I'm not sure one is possible.